# access the value of a selected option in select tag using node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to retrieve the value of a selected option under the select tag.Below is a snippet of my ejs file and I am using node.js Express framework as a server-side language. Below are the options for food items. As soon as an option is selected, a text-field must be fetched by its price from the database. In order to display the price of the selected food item, I require the value of the selected item first. This is the part where I am stuck. I don't know how to trigger an event to do the same as soon as I select the item. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.
This is the HTML file I am having:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body> 
<form action="/bill" method="post">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <select id="foodItem0">
            <option></option>
            <option value="veg_hak_nood">Veg Hakka Noodles</option>
            <option value="alo_par">Aloo Paratha</option>
            <option value="pan_par">Panner Paratha</option>
        </select>  
        <div class="text"><input type="text" id="rate" name="rate" size="2" 
        readonly value="0"></div>
        <div class="btn">
          <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
          <button type="button">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script>
          document.getElementById('submit').onclick=function(){
            rate.value=foodItem0.value;
        }

        </script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the app.js file:-

```
const mysql = require('mysql'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    parser = require('body-parser'),
    router = express.Router();

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "0440",
    database: "kfc"
})

conn.connect(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Database connected")
})

app = express();
app.use(parser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
})

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res){
    res.render('pages/dashboard.ejs')
})

app.post('/dashboard', function(req, res){
    conn.query("select id from login where id = ? and pwd = ?", [req.body.login, req.body.pwd], function(err, result, fields){
        console.log(result);
        if(err) throw err;

        if(result.length > 0){
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
            console.log("Credentials verified")
        }else{
            console.log("Credentials incorrect");
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
})

app.post('/bill', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Hello");  //statement not getting executed
    //HERE I AM TRYING TO CATCH THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED OPTION AND PASS IT INTO A QUERY
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: There is a lot of context missing. node.js is on the server, the select box is in some browser. How would your server know what somebody selected in a browser? It's like asking why Fred cannot eat the bred Wilma put on the table - when Fred is in a house in Alaska and Wilma in a house in Japan. Okay, it's not like that at all but it's the least stupid analogy I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form elements must have name attributes in order to be able to perform a form submit automatically. 
You must however also have a mechanism that will trigger a form submit. You could use javascript or html to do this.

Server-side you would need a function similar to the one below that will be triggered when a specific call is made. Depending on how you submit the request you would need to find the data either in `req.url` as a parameter or `req.body`.

```
const http = require("http");

function request_handler(req, res){
  let url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
  console.log(url_parts)
  console.log(req.body)
  res.end(JSON.stringify("thanks for the request"))
}
const server = http.createServer(request_handler)
server.listen(80, (err)=>{
    if(err) return console.log("error", err);
    console.log("server listening on", port_num)
})
```

I have attempted to answer your question. 
But to give a proper answer we really need to know how you are submitting the form and what type of request you are making to your server.

Comment: Now I got to know that I am stuck with multiple problems. Thanks @WouldBeNerd for helping me out. So, I'll be asking more and more doubts as I encounter them. One of them is mentioned below:-
As soon as I select one of the options, a text field must display its rate that will be fetched from the database. Thus, I want select event to be triggered. How to perform this action?

Comment: @Aman Mathur can you show the html page that you already have; if you are using a js script file, add that one too. Are you using any libraries server side? I think you are missing some fundamental knowledge. It might be a good idea to follow some tutorials first.